# The Azure CLI task on my classic pipeline shows an error using inlinescript

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-cli

I use the [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) on my Azure **classic** pipeline (no YAML). The pipeline works appropriately, the only problem is that this task shows an error. I use this inline script for the task:

```
$containers = $(call az storage container list --connection-string '...') | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 5
$containers | where{$_.name -like "..."}
$lastContainers = $containers | Select-Object -Last 5
$containers.ForEach({ If ($_ -notin $lastContainers) {call az storage container delete --name $_.name --connection-string '...' } });
```

I replaced my real connection string with `...`. I get this error about the last task (Azure CLI) when I run the pipeline (all of the previous steps end successfully):

```
D:\a\9\s>$containers = $(call az storage container list --connection-string '...') | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 5 
'$containers' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
##[error]Script failed with error: Error: The process 'D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1587632019088.bat' failed with exit code 255
```

I have a similar YAML pipeline that uses this same script and everything works just fine. I use `call` in front of Azure commands [as suggested on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11808#issuecomment-557094790).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AzureCLI@2` you select script type:

> Type of script: PowerShell/PowerShell Core/Bat/Shell script. Select
>   bash/pscore script when running on Linux agent or batch/ps/pscore
>   script when running on Windows agent. PowerShell Core script can run
>   on cross-platform agents (Linux, macOS, or Windows)

Additionally there may appear some differences in Linux and Windows (this issue with `call` statement), but if you select there `pscore` for instance you should get rid of 'call` statement.

So please provide more info in what system and terminal you run this script to give you more help.

I ran you script without `call` in powershell and all was fine. Please try run it in that way.

Comment: @RHShanks92 Glad to help, if the answer has helped you solve your problem please upvote it. Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)